# Wildcard in bash script

Tags: bash, wildcard

I have a bash script to retrieve files from ftp.

Now the files have one part a date string in the filename, but also undefined numbers that changes on every file. I want to download the files based on the date.

This is my code. I only need to do the wildcard trick, the ftp script is allready work.

```
filename=$(echo $TIMESTAMP'0***vel.radar.h5')
```

The stars are 3 digits with different numbers that i can't estimate, so i would use the wildcard for them.

Thank you

Comment: What is the question? Also note that `*` stands for any number of characters, so `***` is the same as `*`. The wildcard for one character is `?`.

Comment: I need to download a file from an ftp server with get $filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to handle multiple files, but your script can only handle one file at a time. Furthermore, because you specified FTP, it sounds like the files are on the FTP server, in which case local filename expansion will not help.

You probably want to use the ftp client's `mget` command to download multiple files matching a pattern on the remote side. You also want to include `$TIMESTAMP` as part of the pattern. I'd suggest something like this:

```
ftp remote-hostname <<EOF
cd path/to/log/files
prompt
mget ${TIMESTAMP}0???vel.radar.h5
bye
EOF
```

This uses a here-document (`<<EOF` to `EOF` on a line by itself) to supply input text to the ftp commmand. It will expand the variable `$TIMESTAMP` so it becomes part of the `mget` command, e.g. if $TIMESTAMP was 12345, the ftp command will be told `mget 123450???vel.radar.h5`.

Answer (score 0):

With the ? characters you include not only numbers, but any character. So if you want to include only numbers, you can replace the ??? characters with [0-9][0-9][0-9].

Example:

If you have the following files:

`$ ls
0123vel.h5  0333vel.h5  033vel.h5  0pecvel.h5`

with this ls you show the correct files:

`$ ls 0[0-9][0-9][0-9]vel.radar.h5
0123vel.h5  0333vel.h5`